# wslpath : The term 'wslpath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" in the command vscode

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am getting the error "wslpath : The term 'wslpath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" in the command" when I execute the preceding task in `task.json` in `vscode`.

> Executing task: cmd /c "dotnet publish -r linux-arm -o bin\linux-arm\publish
> "C:\Users\SibeeshVenu\SourceCode\raspberrypi.net.core\raspberrypi.net.core.csproj""
> | bash -c "rsync -rvuz $(wslpath
> 'C:\Users\SibeeshVenu\SourceCode\raspberrypi.net.core')/bin/linux-arm/publish/
> pi@192.168.0.80:~/raspberrypi.net.core"

I am not sure what exactly the problem is. The idea is to deploy my `.net core` application to my Raspberry Pi. I run WSL1 in my Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the default terminal in `VSCode`. So I had to change that to `Command Prompt`. To do that, just press F1 in VSCode and type “Terminal: Select Default Shell”, and then select Command Prompt.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.